# Reading a text file up to a certain character and store different varibles

Tags: c++, c

i have a text file and it includes data like this;

int#char#char

i have to read this and store in ("%d, %s, %s", &number, name, surname) and of course i have many data it has to be in while loop.

i tried but i didnt get how to read until certain character (in my case it is #)

```
void readText()
{
      int number;
      char firstName[20];
      char secondName[20];

      FILE *fp = fopen ("stack.txt", "r");
      if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "file error\n");
        return 255;
      }

      while (fscanf(fp,"%d %s %s", &number, firtName, secondName)>0);
      fclose (fp);
}
```

Comment: So the numbers and the two strings are separated by a literal `#` character? For all the records you read? Then you can place the `#` in the format string, and `fscanf` will try to match it.

Comment: Sidenote: For checking if `fscanf` succeeds or fails, you should check with `== 3` instead of `> 0`. You want to make sure that all 3 parameters are read correctly.